# Number of integral points on rectangular hyperbola $xy=15!$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I came across this question while going through P&C problems.

Let n(P) represents the number of points $P(\alpha,\beta)$ lying on rectangular hyperbola $xy=15!$ under the conditions given in column I, match the values of n(P) given in column II

Column I

(A) $\alpha,\beta \in I$

(B) $\alpha,\beta \in I^+$ and $HCF(\alpha,\beta)=1$

(C) $\alpha,\beta \in I^+$ and $\alpha$ divides $\beta$

(D) $\alpha,\beta \in I^+$ and $HCF(\alpha,\beta)=35$

Column II (P) 32 (Q) 64 (R) 96 (S) 4032 (T) 8064

My approach $xy=15!=2^{11}.3^6.5^3.7^2.11.13$

Total number of positive integral solutions $=12*7*4*3*2*2=4032$
Total number of integral solutions $8064$ So (A) matches with (T)

Total number of coprime factors $=2^5$
Thus n(P) when $\alpha,\beta \in I^+$ and $HCF(\alpha,\beta)=1 = 2*32=64$ So (B) matches with (Q)

For $\alpha,\beta \in I^+$ and $\alpha$ divides $\beta$ exponent of prime in x must be less than or equal to the exponent of prime in y which gives $6*4*2*2*1*1=96$ factors. So, (C) matches with (R)

Finally for $\alpha,\beta \in I^+$ and $HCF(\alpha,\beta)=35$ then exactly 35 must be present in one of x or y and other one must contain either $5,5^2,5^3$ and $7,7^2$ giving us 6*2=12 choices for 5 and 7. Total choices will be $12*7*12*2*2=4032$ So, (D) matches with (S).

I wish to know if the answers are correct and is there a shorter way to approach the problem